# d3.js / migration - simple force simulation example from d3.v3 to d3.v7

Tags: d3.js, drag, d3-force

I would like to run a simple working code with **d3.v7 (7.8.5)** from a **d3.v3** version.
I am looking to have the same behaviours, especially drag.

[image: My Graph]

Any help welcomed.

The code is available here : https://jsfiddle.net/PBrockmann/mq1etbf0/

```js
var force = d3.layout.force()
           .nodes(data.nodes)
           .links(data.links)
           .size([width, height])
           .linkDistance([50])
           .charge([-100])
           .start();
```

Here is a try with **d3.v7.js** : https://jsfiddle.net/PBrockmann/cLnbeujp/

But the drag disappears after one drag.

Answer (score 0):

The following jsfiddle has been updated with a working solution :
https://jsfiddle.net/PBrockmann/cLnbeujp/

```
var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force("link", d3.forceLink().distance(50))
  .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-100))
  .force("collide", d3.forceCollide())
  .force("x", d3.forceX())
  .force("y", d3.forceY())
  .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));
```

and

```
function dragged(event, d) {
  d.fx = event.x;
  d.fy = event.y;
  simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
}
```

0.3 for alphaTarget gives close behaviours observed in d3.v3